# Why is this bone not pointing up / downwards?

Tags: animation

Can anybody tell me why the "N_ALL" bone is laying on the floor?

If the bone is laying on the ground, I expect the model to be laying on the ground, too, but it doesn't. The model's pose doesn't correlate to this root bone for me.

Edit: I have uploaded the [fbx file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aUK8gYVjKqBGsARiZcdTX6MGVmxH673g/view?usp=sharing).

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file so that we understand what is this bone for, it looks like a root bone

Comment: @moonboots I have added a link to the fbx file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the designer of the armature .. or rig decided they needed a convenient handle on the armature. Like a coffee cup has a handle or that plastic attachment for cell phones is a handle. Bones can be used for many different things.  Blender Bones can be for human, monster, and other organic creatures.  Bones can control meshes that represent hard objects as well like a car.  You can change the appearance of bones.  The bones of an armature can have zero or some effect on the mesh.  They are flexible in their use. That bone may serve as a handle to indirectly control other bones which directly control mesh.  That control can be changed or deleted.  If the mesh has a vertex group that has the same names as a bone then it can have some effect.  If you decide to delete the vertex group then that connection will be destroyed. Weight painting can change the weights in a vertex group.

So parenting an armature to a mesh with automatic weights is just one use of armature bones.  Some time you might like to control many things at once and bones can do that as well since you might assign a hard object to each separate bone.

Answer (score 0):

The big bone is the root bone. It is the highest bone in the hierarchy, it is made to control the whole armature in *Pose* mode. It can be useful for example to create walk cycles.

Generally, you need to parent the bottom spine bone and all the *IK* targets and pole target bones to the root bone.

It is not made to deform the mesh, its *Deform* option should be deactivated.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea why the root bone is laying on the floor?

Comment: this is where you generally put your root bone, but you could put it somewhere else

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was odd. Good to know that this isn't the case.

Comment: I need to ask again: Why is it *laying* and not *standing*?

Comment: you could make it stand if you prefer, it doesn't matter, you could also scale it down. But to transform it, switch to Edit mode.